# Android linear layout from right to left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout in which I want to fill with an element from right side to left in XML file. The reason for filling from right to left is rounding error of %, because I want to match to layout on the right side.

One is separate as: `55% - 15% - 15% - 15%`

The other is: `49% - 2% - 34% - 15%`

And all I want is that the right 15%'s are exactly the same, because now it is not the same (maybe 1px or 2px difference).

I tried with direction and with gravity but I didn't get the desired results.

EDITED:

I'm sorry here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <RelativeLayout 
             android:id="@+id/leftSideDefaultHoldeTitleBar"
             android:layout_width="0px"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="49"
             android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
         </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="34"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="0px"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="15"
              android:background="@android:color/blue"
             >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The other layout is the same just with other values in weight, I have booth placed in same holder and when I switch between them is a little mistake at right side.

Comment: It would help to see your layout or code where you add UI elements.

Comment: post your `xml` first. We will correct it with pleasure !

Answer (score 1):

Use weightSum=100 for LinearLayout and set weight for all child views as per your specified percentage .

Comment: Use layout_weight for all the childs of the main layout and set the childs according to the percentage you need. For example if you have two layouts in main layout ser layout_weight = 0.5 for both of them so that both will occupy the whole main layout equally in two parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I find it perfectly same. See attached snapshot

```
[<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="55"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="55"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#f00f"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#0f000f"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="49"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="55"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
             android:background="#f00f"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="34"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
             android:background="#0f000f"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't run it on emulator, I'm running on galaxy S2 and is not the same. And because of all custom views I don't sea graphical my layout

Comment: I tried this and its running fine. Have you tried the above Layout on a device?

Comment: There is no other way you can do this in layout.